# Wordpress add_rewrite_rule with 4 vars is not working

Tags: regex, wordpress, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite a url for a custom page template 
The link http://pm.com/cusotm-page/7170-West-9th-Avenue-Lakewood-CO-80214/29415331/RES/METRO  should be written  as

http://pm.com/cusotm-page/?title=2005-South-Monroe-Street-Denver-CO-80210&ppid=29377927&property=RES&originator=METRO

the code in functions.php is

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpa5413_init' );

function wpa5413_init(){
    add_rewrite_tag('%title%','([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%ppid%','([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%property%','([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%originator%','([^&]+)');

    add_rewrite_rule('^cusotm-page-homendo/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$','cusotm-page/?title=$matches[1]&ppid=$matches[2]&property=$matches[3]&originator=$matches[4]','top');
 }
```

can you tell me what i'm doing wrong? is the regex correct

PS" i flushed the rewrite rules and the get variables are added with add_query_arg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution was to use index.php with pagename on rewrite

```
function wpa5413_init(){

add_rewrite_tag('%title%','([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_tag('%ppid%','([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_tag('%property%','([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_tag('%originator%','([^&]+)');   
add_rewrite_rule('^cusotm-page/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$','index.php?pagename=cusotm-page&title=$matches[1]&ppid=$matches[2]&property=$matches[3]&originator=$matches[4]','top');
 }
```

this will rewrite the url  and links like http://pm.com/cusotm-page/7170-West-9th-Avenue-Lakewood-CO-80214/29415331/RES/METRO would become usable. 
However the  $_GET['title'] will not work - but you can access variables with $wp_query->query_vars['title']

Also make sure you use add_query_arg before displaying the nice link.

Hope it helps somebody...